# Declaring foreign key in django model

Tags: django

I have recently started using django to read out oracle database. I am having a problem with created a model with foreign key.

Here is what I have in Oracle schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MTRS_CHANNELS(ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ALIAS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, BOARDNUMBER int, CHIPNUMBER int, CHANNELNUMBER int, TYPEID int, SYSTEMNAME VARCHAR(255));

ALTER TABLE MTRS_CHANNELS ADD CONSTRAINT uniquesensornaming UNIQUE (BOARDNUMBER , CHIPNUMBER , CHANNELNUMBER, SYSTEMNAME);

CREATE TABLE MTRS_DATA(CHANNELID int NOT NULL, FLAG int, UPDATETIME TIMESTAMP, VALUE FLOAT);

ALTER TABLE MTRS_DATA ADD CONSTRAINT CHANNELIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY (CHANNEL_ID) REFERENCES MTRS_CHANNELS(ID);
```

Basically there are 2 tables MTRS_CHANNELS which stores channels identified by unique channelid and MTRS_DATA stores value for a channel, which is referenced by channelid as foreign key.

In my models.py I have :

```
from django.db import models

class Channel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    boardnumber = models.IntegerField()
    chipnumber = models.IntegerField()
    channelnumber = models.IntegerField()
    typeid = models.IntegerField()
    systemname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
         db_table = "MTRS_CHANNELS"
         managed = False
        
class values(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updatetime = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    class Meta:
         db_table = "MTRS_DATA"
         managed = False
```

The problem is that I am trying to load data in view it complains with:

ORA-00904: "MTRS_DATA"."ID": invalid identifier

When I try to modify channel  to  channel_id in values, I get

ORA-00904: "MTRS_DATA"."CHANNEL_ID_ID": invalid identifier

I might be missing something really obvious but the problem clearly comes from the way Foreign Key is declared.

Thanks and regards,
Ivan

Comment: You already have a table in Oracle and want to use that, is that what you are doing? If so look into using [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) first then making changes to the generated `models.py`.

Comment: Thanks for help. So my idea is to use django to display data from the database in the web interface.

Comment: I have run inspectdb and i get in models:

from django.db import models
# Unable to inspect table 'mtrs_channels'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
# Unable to inspect table 'mtrs_data'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
# Unable to inspect table 'type2id'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier

Comment: Please show your database settings in `settings.py` (hide sensitive information like password etc.) and your Django version, Oracle version.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'HOSTNAME',
 'USER': 'MYUSER',
 'PASSWORD':'MYPASSWORD',
    }
}

Comment: I am able to get data from the database, that's for sure.

Comment: django-admin --version
2.1.15
Oracle client installed on the web server side is : /usr/lib/oracle/19.9/client64/